# json.dumps() fails to convert this string of dictionary

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse the `test_string` to JSON but failing, just continues as string after `json.dumps`, see result below. How can I get the expected output?
The `test_string` is pulled from a text object and that's how it's quoted.

```
test_string = "{'fruit': ['Yes'], 'vegetables': ['carrot']}"

# output
json.dumps(test)
'"{\'fruit\': [\'Yes\'], \'vegetables\': [\'carrot\']}"'

# expected output
{'fruit': ['Yes'], 'vegetables': ['carrot']}
```

Comment: Do you not want to be using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)? `json.dumps` is for creating a string from a python object. Though I don't thing your `test_string` will parse as JSON wants double quotes.

Comment: You can use eval() function to create a dict from String. Then you can use json.dumps()

Comment: @Alex `json.loads` gives a decoding error. `ast.literal_eval` worked

Comment: @Aks [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/) is not Python syntax. JSON requires double quotes for its strings.

Comment: @Alex it's from a text object, that's how it is in the document that is getting parsed, which is why `json.loads` fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ast` and `json`

```
import ast
import json
data = ast.literal_eval("{'fruit': ['Yes'], 'vegetables': ['carrot']}")
print(json.dumps(data))
```

output

```
{"fruit": ["Yes"], "vegetables": ["carrot"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

json.loads() should do the trick

```
test_string = "{'fruit': ['Yes'], 'vegetables': ['carrot']}"
new_test_string = json.loads(test_string)
```

Comment: `json.loads` gives a `JSONDecodeError`. `ast.literal_eval` works